# ColdFusion increasing number count

Tags: coldfusion

Not really sure what to call this, this title is about as close to what I need as I can think of!

Basically, we've set up a competition for a client that assigns more entries to the competition based on how much information is provided. I know I am unclear, but let me try to explain.

In our database, there will be something like

```
Name | Number of Entries 
''''''''''''''''''''''''    
Josh |        3
Mike |        3
Pat  |        1
Raul |        2
```

There is more information than this in the database, of course, but this is a simplified version.

What I want it to do is to run some code that will update the database, assigning values based on how many entries they have, i.e.

```
Name | Number of Entries | Raffle Number(s)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Josh |        3          |      1, 2, 3
Mike |        3          |      4, 5, 6
Pat  |        1          |         7
Raul |        2          |        8, 9
```

etc etc. So the code reads how many entries they have and inserts this many increasing values (based on the last value) into the database.

Let me know if you need any more clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what your're after:

```
<CFQUERY name="qGetStats" datasource="#yourdsn#">
    SELECT id,number_of_entries
    FROM mytable
</CFQUERY>
<CFSET counter = 1 />
<CFLOOP query="qGetStats">
    <CFSET dummy = "" />
    <CFLOOP from="#counter#" to="#counter+qGetStats.number_of_entries-1#" index="idx">
        <CFSET dummy = listappend(dummy,idx) />
    </CFLOOP>
    <CFQUERY datasource="#yourdsn#">
        UPDATE mytable
        SET
        raffle_numbers = <CFQUERYPARAM value="#dummy#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        WHERE id = <CFQUERYPARAM value="#id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
    </CFQUERY>
    <CFSET counter = counter + qGetStats.number_of_entries />
</CFLOOP>
```

I don't get why you need this, but it could be the answer ;-)

Comment: YES! This works amazingly well, thank you so so so so much! :D This needs to be done, as we need to pick a winner from a random number generator, and this allows us to know which raffle numbers correspond with which person, which this has done for me! Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Joshua - Storing delimited values usually leads to headaches.  For example how would you find the owner of raffle number `5`? It is possible, but the sql is awkward and error prone. A more flexible and reliable structure is to create a third table storing each `NameID` and `RaffleNumbers` as a separate record.

Comment: I'll look in the database to find the corresponding row? Or dump them to a CSV and find it manually. The datalist isn't huge so manually seeking the winning ticket owner is completely viable. I understand if I had a bigger list I might have to do it differently, but for this, at least, it isn't necessary as manually finding the winning record is easy enough. This just saved me time in manually assigning raffle numbers. I think I've understood your question, but if not, let me know!

Comment: If the values were stored individually, *as numbers*, finding the corresponding record is a simple: `WHERE RaffleNumber = 5`. But since they are stored as part of a list, finding the corresponding row is more difficult. Not impossible, but it requires more effort than is necessary. Not to mention it is more error prone because you may be matching on strings, not numbers. ie ",5" is different than ",(space)5" or "5.0". Using a separate table with an auto incrementing makes it much easier to both generate and query raffle numbers.

Comment: @Leigh: _For example how would you find the owner of raffle number 5?_ how about `SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5,raffle_numbers)` - it's not that hard.

Comment: @Seybsen - That method still suffers from the string vs number comparison issues mentioned above. It is also mySQL specific, iirc.

Comment: Alternate to FIND_IN_SET for non-MySQL databases http://blogs.digitss.com/database/alternate-to-find_in_set-for-non-mysql-databases/

Comment: @Johshua - I understood you had already made a decision for *yourself* ;) But keep in mind S.O. is archived, so comments help future readers as well. Mentioning common pitfalls makes it easier for the next guy to make the best decision for *his* situation.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely create a table to hold entries and another to hold raffle numbers. Your code will be easier and you will have more data available to you if you need it.

Instead of incrementing numbers, just insert a new record into a table storing raffle numbers for each entry. This will use a little more space in your database, but you will have more data and easier code.

Then just use the following code to get the data as you describe

```
 SELECT EntryID, EntryName
        (
            SELECT  count(*)
            FROM    rafflenumbers
            WHERE   rafflenumbers.EntryID = entries.EntryID
        ) AS NumberOfEntries
 FROM   entries
```

Addressing a sample that came up in comments, you could then easily find an entry with a raffle number of 5.

```
 SELECT     EntryID
 FROM       entries
 INNER JOIN rafflenumbers
    ON      entries.EntryID = rafflenumbers.EntryID
 WHERE      rafflenumbers.Number = 5
```

Comment: That is basically the way I would do it (ie set `RaffleNumber` as auto incrementing so numbers are generated automatically). The few times I used lists, I always ended up regretting it.